# Repair existing CoreData store for 'NSObjectInaccessibleException'

Tags: ios, core-data, ios6

I've come across an existing CoreData app that had incorrect relationships/delete rules set which led to the classic "'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for" when accessing a parent object with children that no longer exist. The relationships and delete rules have been fixed although the existing database still has parent objects that point to children that no longer exist which leads to the fault and a crash.

Is there a way to scan the database and delete references to objects that no longer exist? I have done this manually in the sql file but I need a programatic approach to fix user's existing databases on startup.